# Can I add custom text in Azure Active Directory App consent screen?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365api

Is there a way to add custom text displayed in AAD Consent screen?
I've checked the docs bud didn't seem to find a way (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest)

Since security considerations are an important part of the user journey we want to explain in more detail (or at least place a personalized sentence) in the consent screen and explain why the app needs access to all this data and what it would be used for.

Comment: This would be quite a neat feature. AFAIK, it cannot be done though at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not be able to add custom text that explains why your app needs certain permissions in the consent screen at this point in time. The consent screen does give a brief description of each permission, it would be interesting to hear the specifics of what you would like to customize.

I would encourage you to request this feature on the [Azure AD UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).